# ReferenceError: strides is not defined on a conv2d tensorflowjs

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

i am restarting a old project with tensorflow.
I was reviewing some topics and found this example: https://es.acervolima.com/funcion-tensorflow-js-tf-conv2d/

after a while i moded it to this:

```
//(3x3x3)
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu'

// Input tensor
const x = tf.tensor2d(
    [
        [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
        [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
        [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
        [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
        [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
        [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
        [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
        [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
        [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
        [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
        [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
        [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
        [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
    ]
    )
  console.log('Shape of the input:',x.shape);
    
  // Kernel has been set
  const kernel = tf.tensor3d([
   [[ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]],

   [[ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ]] 
    ]);
    
  console.log('Shape of the kernel:',kernel.shape);
    
  // Output tensor after convolution
  let out = tf.conv2d(x, kernel, strides = 1, 'same');
    
  out.print();
  console.log('Shape of the output:',out.shape)
```

x is just a encoded data an the kernel are the first three lines of x

and i get this output:

```
PS C:\Users\Dua\OneDrive\Documents\server-beeing-beta0.0\utils\tensor> node .\toy.js
2022-01-12 18:57:21.617625: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1350 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0, compute capability: 5.2
Shape of the input: [ 100, 5 ]
Shape of the kernel: [ 2, 12, 5 ]
file:///C:/Users/Dua/OneDrive/Documents/server-beeing-beta0.0/utils/tensor/toy.js:49
  let out = tf.conv2d(x, kernel, strides = 1, 'same');
                                         ^

ReferenceError: strides is not defined
    at file:///C:/Users/Dua/OneDrive/Documents/server-beeing-beta0.0/utils/tensor/toy.js:49:42
```

why strides is not define?
thank you guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

ok, the problem was this:

```
  let out = tf.conv2d(x, kernel, strides = 1, 'same');
```

is not correct, but:

```
  let out = tf.conv2d(x, kernel, 1, 'same');
```